# ruby page-object java script prevents text submit

Tags: javascript, ruby, page-object-gem

I'm new to Ruby and cheezy's page-object test automation framework, but until now I was doing well.
The issue I have is that I can't submit text, nor float into text field that's inside a table on a web page.

I suspect that some javascript is preventing me from entering data. Those fields have default values. When test script submits data, the default value is not over written, but my value is just added inline with default value and when test script continues to another field in that row, the default value is returned!

I cant find the way to submit my data.

Im using Selenium web-driver. env.rb content:

```
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'page-object'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'page-object/page_factory'

World(PageObject::PageFactory)

Before do
  @browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

  @login_page = LoginPage.new(@browser)
end

After do
    @browser.close
end
```

I pass data from cucumber table and try to submit using page-object class text field method:

```
Then(/^I submit input data table$/) do |table5|
  data=table5.hashes 
  on WebPage do |page|

    data.each_with_index do |column, index|
      row = page.bill_table[index + 1]    

      row.price = column["Price"]

    end
  end
end
```

Method definition inside class:

```
indexed_property(:bill_table, [
    [:text_field, :service_description, {:xpath => ".//tbody[@class='ui-sortable']//tr[%s]//td[3]/input"}],
    [:text_field, :quantity, {id: 'output_invoice_items__quantity'}], # {:xpath => ".//tbody[@class='ui-sortable']//tr[%s]//td[4]/input"}],    
    [:text_field, :unit, {:xpath => ".//tbody[@class='ui-sortable']//tr[%s]//td[5]/input"}], 
    [:text_field, :price, {:xpath => ".//tbody[@class='ui-sortable']//tr[%s]//td[6]/input"}],
    [:text_field, :discount, {:xpath => ".//tbody[@class='ui-sortable']//tr[%s]//td[7]/input"}],       
])
```

The data for price is entered, as I said before, only after default data in the same line and when automation script passes to new field, the default value returns!
When i try this manually the script formats the number I enter into float, adds ",00" after the number.

I suspect that javascript prevents entering data. 
Any suggestion on how to solve this?
Is there maybe some option to disable javascript from messing with data?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the element with row.price_element.clear() and then using send_keys: row.price_element.send_keys('Whatever you want here').

Comment: Can you share a link to the page or extract enough html/javascript to reproduce the problem? It is difficult to debug/address these types of problems without an example.